# If I use && to run two commands - do I need to put sudo in once or twice?

Tags: command-line, sudo

Suppose I have the following command

```
curl -Lo .amb j.mp/docker-ambari && . .amb && amb-deploy-cluster
```

(assuming this is running on vagrant - so not a real machine)

And I know I've got a permission issue and want to add sudo - do I need to add it once:

```
sudo curl -Lo .amb j.mp/docker-ambari && . .amb && amb-deploy-cluster
```

or more?

```
sudo curl -Lo .amb j.mp/docker-ambari && sudo . .amb && sudo amb-deploy-cluster
```

Comment: This is a great question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you have to use sudo for each command **or**

you can use

```
sudo sh -c "gedit first; gedit second"
```

Above creates a documets first and second with root privllages. Separate the commands with semicolon <kbd>;</kbd>